# Memoization / dynamic programming in Haskell on 2 or 3 arguments

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming, memoization

Here is a simple memoization in Haskell for function `f1` taking one argument (yes, Fibonacci):

```
f1 = [calc n | n <- [0..]]
     where calc 0 = 0
           calc 1 = 1
           calc n = f1 !! (n-1) + f1 !! (n-2)
```

Now, how would this be done for a function f2 that takes 2 arguments, or f3 that takes 3?

For f2, is the best approach a list of lists? Or can a different data structure be used?

```
f2 = [[calc n m | n <- [0..]] | m <- [0..]]
     where calc 0 0 = 0
           calc a b = // ...something using (f2 !! a !! b)
```

Of for `f3 a b c`, given that `max_a * max_b * max_c` is manageable, how would this memoization / dynamic programming work?

I'm looking for the simplest / most straight forward approach, using standard Haskell libs if possible.

**Edit**

As suggest in Chris Taylor's answer, I tried using `MemoCombinators.hs` v0.5.1 but it fails for me, like this:

```
Could not find module `Data.IntTrie'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

and

```
Illegal symbol '.' in type
Perhaps you intended -XRankNTypes or similar flag
to enable explicit-forall syntax: forall <tvs>. <type>
```

I need this to run in "plain" haskell, this version: `GHCi, version 7.6.3`

Any tips to get it going?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can think of two approaches -

### 1. MemoCombinators

The easiest way to create *generic* memoized functions is probably to use the `data-memocombinators` library. Say you have the following two argument function.

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Integer
f 0 _ = 1
f _ 0 = 1
f a b = f (a-1) b + f a (b-1)
```

You can try calling `f 20 20`, but be prepared to wait a while. You can easily write a memoizing version with

```
import Data.MemoCombinators

f :: Int -> Int -> Integer
f = memo2 integral integral f'
  where
    f' 0 _ = 1
    f' _ 0 = 1
    f' a b = f (a-1) b + f a (b-1)
```

Note that it's important that in the helper function `f'` the recursive calls are *not* to `f'` but rather to the memoized function `f`. Calling `f 20 20` now returns almost instantly.

### 2. Lists of Lists of ...

If you know that the arguments to your function are `Int` and that you will need to use all of `0..n` and `0..m` to compute `f (n+1) (m+1)` then it might make sense to use the list of lists approach. However, note that this scales badly with the number of arguments to the function (in particular, it is difficult to tell at a glance what the function is doing if you have more than 2 arguments).

```
flist :: [[Integer]]
flist = [[f' n m | m <- [0..]] | n <- [0..]]
 where
  f' _ 0 = 1
  f' 0 _ = 1
  f' a b = flist !! (a-1) !! b + flist !! a !! (b-1)

f :: Int -> Int -> Integer
f a b = flist !! a !! b
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks very much for your answer, I think I need to use option 1. and pull out the bare minimum of code from data-memocombinators package, it looks like I just need `type Memo` and `memo2`, `memo3`, does that sound right?

Comment: @vikingsteve You will also need `integral` from MemoCombinators. I'll take a look at your errors. It looks like you don't have the `data-inttrie` library. It should be installed automatically if you run `cabal install data-memocombinators` but you could also try `cabal install data-inttrie` to get it. Does that help?

Comment: @vikingsteve Note that `data-memocombinators` uses two extensions, Rank2Types and ScopedTypeVariables ([package description here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators-0.3/data-memocombinators.cabal)). If you don't want to depend on packages that use extensions then this won't be suitable. However, you won't need to enable those extensions in your own modules, so it may be acceptable for you.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think I will go and read the `data-inttrie` library (it seems to be some super-efficient bitwise data structure, perhaps I can do something similar with `Data.Map` ?) and then use `type Memo`, `wrap`, `integral` and `memo2` to have a custom, "no external libraries" implementation of what I need.

Comment: @vikingsteve You should also check out [this page on memoization](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization). My experience with using a `Data.Map` for memoization was that it was very difficult to get it to work for functions with more than 2 arguments, because I couldn't get the maps to be lazy enough. But maybe you will have better luck!

Comment: Just an addendum - your second solution (List of Lists) works equally well, and much more simply, without external libraries!

Answer (score 2):

Since Haskell is lazy, you can memoise a function by calling it on itself.

for example, one fibonacci generator in Haskell is this:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

(from http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence)

which, uses the resulting list as its own storage for state.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can I use this lazy memoization with a function with 2 or 3 arguments that returns one Int?